# Getting the largest image from HTML page source in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get an image to represent a page (for quick browsing in a XAML GridView).

I have the pages URL (and it's HTML content), but now I'm not completely sure how to proceed. I could just use the Favicon, but I don't think that would scale well up to the 200x200 box I'm using to display it. The other option (as far as I can think of) is to look through the HTML source and pick out the largest image.

Is there an easier/simpler way to do that in C# other than just using Regexs to find the height/width of all the image tags and then comparing them?

Thanks!

Comment: 200x200 is almost largest enough to consider rendering the page yourself (in the background) and capturing a screenshot of it and storing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to know for sure from the HTML source what size the images are. An `img` tag doesn't require the `height` and `width` parameters. If they're not specified, then the image is displayed in its actual size. If all the `img` tags on the page have their height and width specified, you could pick the one that has the largest values. But those are the *display* sizes. The actual sizes might be quite different.

The only way to be 100% sure is to download each image and get its size.

By the way, if you're parsing HTML, you probably shouldn't be doing it with regular expressions. I know it seems simple enough, but you're almost certain to get things wrong and not handle some common cases. You'll save yourself a lot of time and frustration by using something like the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
imageObject.ActualWidth 

imageObject.ActualHeight
```

properties

Comment: sorry, I might not have made my question clear, I have HTML code saved in a string and I'm trying to extract the source of the largest image in that HTML code. I'm not trying to get the largest image in the current XAML page

Comment: Regex you don't want to use.. the other is that you can try XMLParser to get the img tag